# Best way to request unknown number of API pages in useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm trying to write a React functional component that requests a list of people exposed across multiple pages in an API:

https://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=9

I know there are currently nine pages, but this might change in the future, so I want my component to keep requesting pages until there are no more, and to accumulate and store the people in the `"results"` bit of each response body. I'm trying to do this with `useState` and `useEffect` hooks.

Is there a common way of solving this problem that's generally considered the best approach?
Could someone show me how to modify my existing code to get it working in the optimal way please?

My current code causes the browser to get stuck endlessly loading.

Was I wrong to try and handle the entire process in the first and only execution of `useEffect`? Should my `useState` have a dependency array that gets passed `page` so that `useEffect` executes again every time `page` is updated?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function GetAllPeople() {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1)
  const [people, setPeople] = useState([]);
  const [gotEveryone, setGotEveryone] = useState(false)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)

  const requestData = () => (
    fetch(`https://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=${page}`)
      .then(res => {
        if (res.ok) {
          let response = res.json()
          setPeople(people.concat(response.results))
          setPage(page + 1)
        } else if(res.status === 404) {
          setGotEveryone(true)
        } else {
          setError(res.status)
          return Promise.reject('some other error: ' + res.status)
        }
    })
  )

  useEffect(() => {
    while(gotEveryone === false) {
      if (!error) {
        requestData()
      }
    }
  })

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {people.map((person, index) =>
          <li key={index}>
            {person.name}
          </li>
        )}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export default GetAllPeople;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Unnecessary hooks.. work with api data (Recursion call)

I make a codesandbox with mock data to save api request (for development)

https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-field-i89yu

> but the main idea is here:

using next key in api response:
[image]

You can make it more elegant:

```
function GetAllPeople() {
  const [people, setPeople] = useState([]);

  const requestData = useCallback((url = 'https://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=1') => (
    fetch(url)
      .then(async res => {
        const response = await res.json();
        setPeople(prevState => prevState.concat(response.results));
        if (response.next) {
          requestData(response.next.replace("http://", "https://"));
        } else {
          console.log("Finish !");
        }
      }).catch(err => {
        throw err;
      })
  ), []);

  useEffect(() => {
    requestData();
  }, [requestData]);

  return (
    ...
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks Omer, but can you explain why you added `requestData` to `useEffect` dependency array?  My understanding is this will make `useEffect` happen again each time `requestData` value changes, but why would we need that when everything that needs to happen is done the first time the callback fires because of the recursion? So wouldn't `useEffect` only need to happen once? Sorry if I've missed something.

Comment: yes, because of the recursion right.
and you are right and smart, you do not have the DI there...
you can do even like that and move out the `requestData`:
(https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-tharp-l9hfq)

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Disclosure: I am the library author of [suspense-service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/suspense-service)</sub>

Using React [Suspense for Data Fetching](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html), and building on the suggestion provided by [Omer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65874041), you can load your results by creating a stateful service to iterate over each of the API endpoints:

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;
const { createService, useServiceState } = SuspenseService;

const FetchJSON = createService((url) => (
  fetch(url).then((res) => res.json())
));

function useFetch() {
  return useServiceState(FetchJSON);
}

function People() {
  const [data, setUrl] = useFetch();
  const [people, setPeople] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const { next, results } = data;
    if (next) setUrl(next);
    setPeople(prev => prev.concat(results));
  }, [data]);

  const list = people.map(({ name, url }) =>
    <li key={url}>
      {name}
    </li>
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {list}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <FetchJSON.Provider
      request="https://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=1"
      fallback={<p>Loading...</p>}
    >
      <People />
    </FetchJSON.Provider>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/suspense-service@0.2.6/dst/umd/suspense-service.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

You can even paginate the results and render a functioning "previous" and "next" button using the response data if you enable concurrent mode:

```js
const { useEffect, useState, unstable_useTransition: useTransition } = React;
const { unstable_createRoot: createRoot } = ReactDOM;
const { createService, createStateContext, useService, useStateContext } = SuspenseService;

const FetchJSON = createService((url) => (
  fetch(url).then((res) => res.json())
));

const Page = createStateContext();

function useFetchJSON() {
  return useService(FetchJSON);
}

function usePageState() {
  return useStateContext(Page);
}

function People() {
  const data = useFetchJSON();
  const [page] = usePageState();

  const list = data.results.map(({ name, url }) =>
    <li key={url}>
      {name}
    </li>
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Page {page}</p>
      <ul>
        {list}
      </ul>
      <p>
        <PageButton delta={-1} disabled={!data.previous}>
          Previous
        </PageButton>
        {' '}
        <PageButton delta={+1} disabled={!data.next}>
          Next
        </PageButton>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}

function PageButton({ delta, disabled, children }) {
  const [, setPage] = usePageState();
  const [startTransition, isPending] = useTransition();

  const onClick = () => {
    startTransition(() => {
      setPage(prev => prev + delta);
    });
  };

  return (
    <button disabled={disabled || isPending} onClick={onClick}>
      {isPending ? 'Loading...' : children}
    </button>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Page.Provider value={1}>
      <Page.Consumer>
        {page => (
          <FetchJSON.Provider
            request={`https://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=${page}`}
            fallback={<p>Loading...</p>}
          >
            <People />
          </FetchJSON.Provider>
        )}
      </Page.Consumer>
    </Page.Provider>
  );
}

createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<App />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@experimental/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@experimental/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/suspense-service@0.2.6/dst/umd/suspense-service.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Hello @patrick-roberts thanks for this, your Suspense for Data Fetching library looks really interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dependency array of `page` so that the `requestData` only gets called on mount, and after a response of the prior page comes back. Don't use `while` - that'll *block*, preventing the app from loading at all.

You also need to fix the request you make - `.json` returns a Promise, you need to wait for it to resolve before accessing the result values.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;
function App() {
    const [page, setPage] = useState(1)
    const [people, setPeople] = useState([]);
    const [gotEveryone, setGotEveryone] = useState(false)
    const [error, setError] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!gotEveryone && !error) {
            fetch(`https://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=${page}`)
              .then(res => {
                  if (res.status === 404) setGotEveryone(true);
                  else return res.json()
                      .then((result) => {
                          console.log('got result', page);
                          // if people or page could be set elsewhere,
                          // use the callback form instead below
                          setPeople(people.concat(result.results));
                          setPage(page + 1);
                      });
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                  setError(res.err);
              })
        }
    }, [page]);

    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {people.map((person, index) =>
                    <li key={index}>
                        {person.name}
                    </li>
                )}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: To follow the rules of hooks, `requestData()` should be moved into `useEffect()` and the functional updates should be used, e.g. `setPeople(prev => prev.concat(result.results)); setPage(prev => prev + 1);`

Comment: If the rules of hooks were being validated, React would throw an error, right? Some might prefer that style, but it makes the logic a bit harder to understand at a glance IMO, and it doesn't impact the working functionality of the code

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach if you're tending to load all people in your component once without pagination or more loading:

```js
  const requestData = async (page, result = []) => {
    const response = await fetch(`https://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=${page}`);
    let data = await response.json();
    if (response.status === 200) {
      result.push(...data.results);
      return requestData(++page, result);
    }

    console.log(result); // all people
    return data;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    requestData(1, []);
  }, []);
```

You're calling `requestData` once in the `useEffect` then you're recursively calling it with different pages, and saves the result in it without any state mutations every time, And in the final call you setting the state safely.

This's not the complete code for your question, but another approach, You can edit this code, to mutate page, or setting errors.

Comment: Thanks for this @zeyad-etman it's a very succinct, elegant approach.